# Question on three.js documentation -- object property vs. hexadecimal string parameter

Tags: parameters, three.js

From the threejs doc for MeshBasicMaterial:

> Constructor MeshBasicMaterial( parameters : Object ) parameters -
> (optional) an object with one or more properties defining the
> material's appearance. Any property of the material (including any
> property inherited from Material) can be passed in here.
>
> The exception is the property color, which can be passed in as a
> hexadecimal string and is 0xffffff (white) by default. Color.set(
> color ) is called internally.

What does it mean "can be passed in as a hexadecimal string"?
The following code has **MeshBasicMaterial(0xff0000)** and it doesn't work.
And I've looked at three.js and don't see any checking for parameter type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
//      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(0xff0000); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
      const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( cube );
      camera.position.z = 5;
      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      };
      animate();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to pass the argument as a hexadecimal string. You need to pass *the color property* in the parameters object as a hexadecimal string.

`new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });`

Then [internally](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/97f98999a0161d03c5dc459fb2aa9db888037707/src/materials/Material.js#L143-L146) the material will call `Color.set(color)`

The "exception" it describes is that `color` is the only property where you're not required to pass an object of its type `Color`. For example:

- aoMap: Needs to be `THREE.Texture`
- color: Could be `THREE.Color` **or** hex `0xffffff` value.

Comment: Thank you -- but then what does `The exception is the property color, which ..` refer to?

Comment: @dcromley I just added an extra explanation to specify.